# Tab-Completion for ValidateSet for Powershell Cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, validateset

I am using C# to create PowerShell cmdlets. For one of the parameters, I am using [`ValidateSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714434.aspx).

```csharp
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
[ValidateSet(new string[]{"STANDARD", "CUSTOM","MINIMUM","DEFAULT"},IgnoreCase=true)]
[Parameter(
    Mandatory = true,
    ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = false,
    ValueFromPipeline = false,
    HelpMessage = "House Mode")
]
[Alias("hm")]
public string HouseMode
{
    get { return m_housemode; }
    set { m_housemode = value;  }
}
```

How can I make the value of the `ValidateSet` appear in the tab-completion list?

Comment: I have never written a cmdlet in C# before, but when I write a function in Powershell with a `[ValidateSet()]` attribute, it automatically tab completes the values for that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the Format-Hex command in PSCX:

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName = ParameterSetObject,
           ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
           HelpMessage = "The encoding to use for string InputObjects.  Valid values are: ASCII, UTF7, UTF8, UTF32, Unicode, BigEndianUnicode and Default.")]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty]
[ValidateSet("ascii", "utf7", "utf8", "utf32", "unicode", "bigendianunicode", "default")]
public StringEncodingParameter StringEncoding
{
    get { return _encoding; }
    set { _encoding = value; }
}
```

Tab completion works on this parameter.  In your case, I think you want to specify the attribute like this:

```
[ValidateSet("STANDARD", "CUSTOM","MINIMUM","DEFAULT", IgnoreCase = true)]
```

Comment: It did not work for me. Do I nned to specify any other attribute or add any configuration file ??

Comment: I mean, How do you specify StringEncodingParameter ? That is the key. Is it a simple C# enum  or you specify in a script or configuration file ?

Comment: You can see the implementation here https://pscx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Trunk/Src/Pscx.Core/StringEncodingParameter.cs  That impl is a bit complex.  I think you could define a C# enum and use that as the parameter type and get the parameter validation check for free.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplication you can also encode the valid values in an enum as follows. This is how I did it in PowerShell directly, but presumably declaring an enum in your c# code would work the same e.g.:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    public enum ContourBranch
    {
       Main,
       Planned,
       POP,
       Statements
    }
"@
```

Then declare your parameter as of that new type, viz

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ContourBranch] $Branch 
)
```

This gives you tab completion and if you get the value wrong the error message also lists the valid enum values, which is pretty neat.